# sed fails with errors

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to replace the next string with sed in all the files in the current directory : (including apostrophe)
'Control_Reports_Pg.C_Table_Title_Date'

with the string : 
timeofday()::varchar(250)

I tried to escape the special characters ' ( ) with the command :

```
sed -i '\''Control_Reports_Pg.C_Table_Title_Date\''/timeofday\(\)::varchar\(250\)/g' *
```

The error I got : `sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unknown command:`_'

I read online that I dont need to escape underscore so what can I do ? When I try to escape underscore with \ i also get an error :

```
sed -i 'Pg.C\_Table\_Title_Date\''/timeofday\(\)::varchar\(250\)/g' *
sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unknown command: `\'
```

Thanks..

Comment: Where is `s/` ? Replace command has the syntax `s///`

Comment: You're missing the command, as pointed out; you don't have to escape `()` in the substitution string; you should escape `.` in the pattern; if you use `"` around your command, you don't have to treat `'` special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i.bak "s/'Control_Reports_Pg.C_Table_Title_Date'/timeofday()::varchar(250)/g" *
```

Never hurts to make a backup file ;}

Comment: I run : sed -i.bak "s/current_setting('Control_Reports_Pg.C_Table_Title_D
ate')/timeofday()/g" * but I get an error - sed: -e expression #1, char 53: unterminated `s' command
(I changed the original string a little bit..)